# Authentication problems when upgrading to SpeechClient v1

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

In the project we have been using the `google/cloud` package's SpeechClient. I'm now in the process of upgrading it to the not deprecated /V1/SpeechClient, but I'm having an issue where I get the following error

```
"Google\ApiCore\ApiException: {
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https:\/\/developers.google.com\/identity\/sign-in\/web\/devconsole-project.",
    "code": 16,
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": []
}
```

This authentication info works in the previous version, and I've tried to change to the new ways it wants me to authenticate, but I guess I'm not doing it correctly. Any help?

---

Previous setup:

```php
    // $auth is keyfile in an Array format. it matches the design given in here, with the edit fields filled
    // https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete#iam-service-account-keys-create-console
    $auth = [
         "type" => "service_account",
         "project_id" => "<project_id>",
         "private_key_id" => "<private_key_id>",
         "private_key" => "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<key>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
         "client_email" => "<the gserviceaccount.com>",
         "client_id" => "<client_id>",
         "auth_uri" => "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
         "token_uri" => "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
         "auth_provider_x509_cert_url" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
         "client_x509_cert_url" => "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/<our url>.gserviceaccount.com",
    ];
    $speech = new Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient([
        'keyFile' => $auth,
    ]);


    // Same auth used for storageClient
    $storage = new Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient([
        'keyFile' => $auth
    ]);
```

Upgraded:

```php
    // $auth is the same as above

    $creds = CredentialsWrapper::build([
        'keyFile' => $auth
    ]);

    // Create the speech client
    $speech = new Google\Cloud\Speech\V1\SpeechClient([
        'credentials' => $creds,
    ]);


    // old auth still used for Storage
    $storage = new Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient([
        'keyFile' => $auth
    ]);

    ...

    $operation = $speech->longRunningRecognize(
            $config,
            $audio
        );

    // gives me output as normal
    $operation->getName();

    // throws exception at the top of the post
    $operation->reload();
```

Comment: can you try to use the application default credentials by putting this line of code before instantiate the client: `putenv( "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json" );`? remove the credential parameter from the SpeechClient constructor.

Comment: @GangChen we don't want to have a file on the server for this, and we have it saved in the database instead, where we parse it from JSON string

Comment: The error message means the client is not using credentials. Verify that `$creds` is valid.

Comment: @JohnHanley The `$auth` passed to it, we use the same credentials with non-V1 SpeechClient in our production and it also works on my environment when I run it thru in the branch without the upgrade. Is there something I can do with the wrapper to confirm it is valid?

Answer (score 0):

it could be that The Application Default Credentials are not available. Try to login by running

gcloud auth application-default login

And follow the instructions, reference: [gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)

If you want to make sure the authentication process went well,

run: gcloud auth application-default print-access-token

You should see an access token, reference [gcloud auth application-default print-access-token](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token)

Comment: We don't authenticate like that, currently pass the contents of the keyfile to the SpeechClient and it works. I'll add more details to the post